# How to improve omega-3 fatty acid absorption?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, supplement, omega-3

I'm going to add an omega-3 supplement in my diet using encapsulated fish oil pills.
I want to know how can I improve its absorption, and also understand why.
That is the boundary conditions:

- ***when***, empty stomach or after the meal
- how, paired with "***friends***" foods

e.g.: I've read [*(source in Italian)*](https://3omega3.it/si-assumono-gli-omega-3-migliorarne-lassorbimento/#Quando_assumere_gli_Omega_3_per_migliorare_il_loro_assorbimento_perche_e_importante) that you can maximize the absorption if you eat pills paired with milk or not-fermented cheese, like mozzarella.

**EDIT:** introduction of omega-3 is by encapsulated fish oil pills
**EDIT2:** as @cloudnyn3 pointed out, I want to know the best conditions which let the pills to be best absorbed

Comment: Not an answer exactly, but here. I have used this treatment for malabsorption issues of fatty acids. It's definitely showed improvement.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2701654/

Comment: In a healthy person with a healthy gut, fats, in general, are completely or nearly completely absorbed. So, I do not understand why would you need to improve absorption of omega-3 fats.

Comment: @Jan you comment is usefulness: A) put credits of your statement (a text, a book, a research, ...) B) if I need it (omega-3), you can easily imagine I may be in a more complex/imperfect health state C) I'm talking about a specific acid fat

Comment: I assuma by omega-3 you mean fish oil...? Also, mentioning the underlying problem can help you get an useful answer.

Comment: @cloudnyn3 thanks for your feedback but it does not contain any useful information for this issue because it deals with emulsified VS encapsulated on equal condition, while I'm looking for the opposite: which condition for the encapsulated-only supplement.